# Import sqlite help

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm struggling to achieve what seems to me should be a simple goal.

I have a long list of vaule I want imported in to a database in one column with many rows.

I have no problems getting the data in in one row and many colums, but I can't figure out how to do it the other way round.

Is that possible??? if not is it possible to alter the table once the data in imported to swap to a manyx1 from a 1xmany table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I need your code to help

Comment: The data just looks like : vaule1;vaule2;value3;vaule4;vaule5;ect I have been using the import function in sqlite browser or the firefox plugin as I'm not really very good at SQL

Answer (score 3):

As with any other database, if you want 10 rows of data, you have to perform 10 insert operations. So you would just loop over your list of values and for each one insert a new row into the database.